# Adding a WMS - connection timed out?

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to add a WMS service to qgis but am having some problems. After adding the url and name of the service and clicking on connect, I am receiving the following error message:-

"Could not understand the response.  The wms provider said:
Download of capabilities failed: Connection timed out"

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: it the WMS server up?

Comment: Is it a publically accessible WMS out fo your control or is it one you control?

Comment: Can you provide the link to the WMS service?

Comment: Is it actually a WMS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your proxy, you don't have internet access directly, so check "use proxy" in options-->network and add your proxy details, did it work ?

Comment: The response suggests that proxy is not an issue.